# React API elements not displaying on page

Tags: reactjs, api

I've been looking for about 2 hours into why I am not displaying any of the information to the page.  I've console logged my response from a simple random quote api and it shows, Author:  and Quote: in the console, however these are not appearing in my fields, All I am seeing is the button.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import QuoteMachine from './Quotemachine';


const END_POINT = 'https://random-quote- 
generator.herokuapp.com/api/quotes/random';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        quote: {
            text: '',
            author: ''
        }
    }
}

getQuote() {
fetch(END_POINT)
    .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            this.setState = ({
                quote: response
            });
            console.log(response);
        })
    }

componentDidMount() {
    this.getQuote();
    }



render() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="container">
                <QuoteMachine quote= {this.state.quote} />
                <button id="new-quote" className="primary-color- 
 background" onClick={() => this.getQuote()}>New quote</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
}
export default App;
```

And then here is my Quotemachine.js

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const QuoteMachine = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="quote-box">
            <div className="text">
            <span>{props.quote.text}</span>
            </div>
            <div className="author">
            <span >{props.quote.author}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

QuoteMachine.propTypes = {
    quote: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default QuoteMachine;
```

It is only displaying the button, but the console.log shows

Object
author:
"Thomas Henry Huxley (1825-1895)"

quote:
"Try to learn something about everything and everything about something."
**proto**
:
Object

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(props);` within `<QuoteMachine />` ?

Comment: are you setting your state correctly? `this.setState = ({
                quote: response
            });` shouldn't it be `this.setState({quote: {text: response.text, author: response.author}})` ?

Comment: Ok, I changed that this.setState and it worked for the author, now that is finally showing up!  but the text: response.text still displays nothing

Comment: Use the React Developer Tools or log the values to console, that you are receiving/passing so you know what you have

Comment: console.logging props in quotemachine returns text is undefined

Comment: Try this `this.setState({quote: {text: response.quote, author: response.author}})`. The API is returning `quote` and `author` so you should accordingly update your state.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thanks Sangom,  The API only returns a Quote, and Author..  So in this instance, I was trying to match text with "text" from the API and it was returning undefined?  

Using text:response.quote redefines the "quote" field from the api into what I am calling text correct?  Do you always have to match the fields from an api in order for them to work?  

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You must reference to them as they are in API, but state can be whatever you want.

Comment: @Sangsom Anything else you can see that I can do to improve my codes readability / functionality?

Comment: Well I would use `object destructuring` e.g. in your `QuoteMachine` component instead to write a long code to get a text `{props.quote.text}` you could write `const { text, author } = props.quote;` and after you can access these values just by calling variable `<span>{text}</span>` also this can be done for methods too. You can read more https://wesbos.com/destructuring-objects/

Answer (score 0):

Install `React Developer Tools` plugin and check if your state is changing after the API call